# IOS Keyboard wont dismiss when using search bar in react site

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, safari, mobile-safari

I am probably taking the wrong approach but I am working on a react site that has a search bar. On IOS/Safari if the user taps into the search the keyboard appears, but pressing done won't dismiss it, it just flicks down for a second and reappears.

I don't have much experience with react yet so I am unsure what the best approach is, so far I have tried writing a js function that uses blur when the focus changes but I can't get it to run yet so I don't know if this will work.

These are the two ways I've tried writing my function:

```
focusOut = () => {
    onToggleOpen();
    e.target.blur();
    console.log('Function has run');
}

function focusOut() {
    onToggleOpen();
    e.target.blur();
    console.log('Function has run');
}
```

And here is how I am currently trying to activate it:

```
<Search onfocusout={this.focusOut} />
```

Apologies if I am looking at this in the wrong way entirely, any suggestions are welcome.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use built-in `Keyboard` module:

```
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native';

Keyboard.dismiss();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! That looked very promising, in the end it turned out there was some other script that was forcing focus, so it was just a case of removing that. In this case, the issue was self-inflicted. Thanks for your help anyway:)